# How to remove hyperlink underline when forwarding email

Tags: html, css, email, hyperlink, html-email

So I'm creating email templates from a program called *Marketo* when I send that email to myself for testing it looks fine, but when I forward that same email the recipient gets all links with an *underline*. How can I not make the blue line appear? This only happens on *Outlooks*.
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use inline css to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea to solve your problem by using *inline style* with an `!important` expression.

You can do it in the following way:

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none!important;">Click here</a>
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it appears on *Outlook* right.

OK, do one thing please once add your so we can't try, please style using inline concept for example below:

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">link</a>
```

Please keep note that you using inline styling here in the email template.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this CSS property:

```
a{ text-decoration: none; }
```

If you want it on mouse hover:

```
a:hover{ text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: You can try the power refresh (ctrl+f5). If the problem remains same then open the page after deleting the browser history or try to open in another browser. You can go with incognito tab. I think this will work for you. If you are using this on a live project then clear the cache from there.